# Fill missing values in a dataframe based on other cell values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large list of names and I am trying to cull down the duplicates. I am grouping them by name and consolidating the info if need be.

When two people don't have the same name it is no problem, we can just ffill and bfill, however, if two people have the same name we need to do some extra checks

This is an example of a group:

```
             name        code            id country     yob
1137  Bobby Joe   USA19921111           NaN     NaN     NaN
2367  Bobby Joe           NaN    1223133121     USA    1992
4398  Bobby Joe   USA19981111           NaN     NaN     NaN
```

The code contains the persons country and birthdate. Looking at it, we can see that the first and second row are the same person. So we need to fill the info from the second row into the first row:

```
             name        code            id country     yob
1137  Bobby Joe   USA19921111    1223133121     USA    1992
4398  Bobby Joe   USA19981111           NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Here is what I have:

```
# Get create a dictionry of all of the rows that contain
# codes and their indexes
code_rows = dict(zip(list(group['code'].dropna().index),
                     group['code'].dropna().unique()))
no_code_rows = group.loc[pd.isnull(group['code']), :]

if no_code_rows.empty or len(code_rows) == group.shape[0]:
    # No info to consolidate
    return group

for group_idx, code in code_rows.items():
    for row_idx, row in no_code_rows.iterrows():
        country_yob = row['country'] + str(int(row['yob']))
        if country_yob in code:
            group.loc[group_idx, 'id'] = row['id']
            group.loc[group_idx, 'country'] = row['country']
            group.loc[group_idx, 'yob'] = row['yob']
            group.drop(row_idx, inplace=True)
            # Drop from temp table so we don't have to iterate 
            # over an extra row
            no_code_rows.drop(row_idx, inplace=True)'''
            break

return group
```

This works but I have a feeling I am missing something? I feel like I shouldn't have to use two loops for this and that maybe there is a pandas function?

EDIT

We don't know the order or how many rows we will have in each group

i.e.

```
       name             code            id country     yob
1137 Bobby Joe   USA19921111           NaN     NaN     NaN
2367 Bobby Joe   USA19981111           NaN     NaN     NaN
4398 Bobby Joe           NaN    1223133121     USA    1992`
```

Comment: There are only 2 rows of data for each code? NaNs row is always first?

Answer (score 0):

I think need:

```
m = df['code'].isnull()
df1 = df[~m]
df2 = df[m]

df = df1.merge(df2, on='name', suffixes=('','_'))
df['a_'] = df['country_'] + df['yob_'].astype(str)
m = df.apply(lambda x: x['a_'] in x['code'], axis=1)
df.loc[m, ['id','country','yob']] = df.loc[m, ['id_','country_','yob_']].rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip('_'))
df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.endswith('_')]
print (df)
        name         code          id country   yob
0  Bobby Joe  USA19921111  1223133121     USA  1992
1  Bobby Joe  USA19981111         NaN     NaN   NaN
```

Comment: This is what I am doing if all of the info in the group pertains to one person.

Unfortunately, we can't know if the rows will be in order.